# How can I receive messages as RDD instead of DStream from a realtime source with a custom receiver?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming, rdd, custom-receiver

I want to get RDD from a realtime message source (currently socket) to replace the line of code that is used to read from a local file `sc.newAPIHadoopFile()`. In order to maintain the structure of the project, I have to get RDD instead of DStream from that source. I tried to implement a custom receiver, but `StreamingContext.receiverStream()` only gives me a DStream. How can I do?

I tried to convert a DStream to RDD with `compute`, but that doesn’t make any sense and I failed. So I turned to discover how to directly receive RDD with a receiver.

Comment: `DStream.foreachRDD`

Comment: Do you mean union all the RDD’s from an DStream? Can you provide more details plz? thanks a lot.